# Updating local database to replicate server database

Tags: mysql

I have a production database on unix server which I deal with using phpMyAdmin and a local test copy on my pc which I deal with using phpMyAdmin from Wamp server.  Manually, or better through a schedule, it would be beneficial to have the pc data updated to replicate the actual production data.

I think I can probably use a cron job to copy the data from one place on the server to another but probably not directly to the pc.  Even if I could it would probably not be in a format that I can use.  How do others solve this common problem please.

Note:  At the moment, even if I manually export and download the whole database to the pc using phpMyAdmin I can't seem to import it back over the Wamp version. Errors about tables already existing stop this and there is no overwrite option.  Even if I give up on the schedule, I would like some help with simply overwriting what I have with a download without having to delete and replace one table at a time from an export.

Comment: if you want the schema of the server, delete your local database. Export the server's complete SQL (DDL and data) and run it on your local copy. If you just want the data, then export the data in csv/sql and upload to your local database. phpMyAdmin provides both option afaik

Comment: Thanks, so there is no overwrite.  I will need to rename my local database, create a new one with the original name and then import the downloaded SQL/ZIP file.

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin on the Export, if you click the `Custom - display all possible options`

You will be presented with a whole set of export based options.

One of those is

```
Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT / TRIGGER statement
```

If you check the checkbox the export will add code to itself to drop the tables before trying to restore them on your WAMPServer MySQL.

Of course you could also just use `phpMyAdmin` on your WAMPServer system to drop all the tables before you run the Restore.

Comment: Thanks for the help